# Structure of my database design?

Tags: mysql-5

I've been developing a C# Bus System app using SQL, and I need some advice. I don't know if asking on here is the right thing to do, but I essentially need someone to analyse the .SQL file I have, where I have designed my database schema. Primary questions are really, is this designed in the right way (what is the right way?), are having UUIDs as primary keys for EVERY table necessary? Should it just be for the institution table? etc.

I don't know if there is anywhere I can go to pay an hour of their time to analyse it....

The SQL file is 430 lines long so, i've pasted it below, I apologise if this is not the right thing to do on here!

Thanks ^.^

```
-- version 5.0.2
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: edu-route-test-db.cqobdbj3xwim.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306
-- Generation Time: Feb 28, 2021 at 01:45 PM
-- Server version: 8.0.20
-- PHP Version: 7.3.21

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `EduRouteDB`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `addresses`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `addresses`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `addresses` (
  `AddressId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  `BuildingName` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `StreetName` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `Town` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `County` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `PostCode` varchar(8) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AddressId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `bookings`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bookings`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookings` (
  `BookingId` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `StudentId` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `StartDate` date NOT NULL,
  `EndDate` date NOT NULL,
  `TimeBooked` time NOT NULL,
  `RouteId` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `StopId` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `UserId` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `InstitutionId` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`BookingId`),
  KEY `StudentId_Bookings_FK` (`StudentId`),
  KEY `RouteId_Bookings_FK` (`RouteId`),
  KEY `StopId_Bookings_FK` (`StopId`),
  KEY `InstitutionId_Bookings_FK` (`InstitutionId`),
  KEY `UserId_Bookings_FK` (`UserId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `buses`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `buses`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `buses` (
  `BusId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  `BusName` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `VehicleRegistrationNumber` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Capacity` int NOT NULL,
  `InstitutionId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  PRIMARY KEY (`BusId`),
  KEY `InstitutionId_Buses_FK` (`InstitutionId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `buses_routes`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `buses_routes`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `buses_routes` (
  `BusId` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `RouteId` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `InstitutionId` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  KEY `BusId_BusesRoutes_FK` (`BusId`),
  KEY `RouteId_BusesRoutes_FK` (`RouteId`),
  KEY `InstitutionId_BusesRoutes_FK` (`InstitutionId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `drivers`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `drivers`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `drivers` (
  `DriverId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  `DriverName` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `BusId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  `InstitutionId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  `UserId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  PRIMARY KEY (`DriverId`),
  KEY `BusId_Drivers_FK` (`BusId`),
  KEY `InstitutionId_Drivers_FK` (`InstitutionId`),
  KEY `UserId_Drivers_FK` (`UserId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `institutions`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `institutions`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `institutions` (
  `InstitutionId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  `InstituteName` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InstituteLogoFullPath` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InstituteJoinDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `IsActive` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PrincipalName` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AddressId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  PRIMARY KEY (`InstitutionId`),
  KEY `AddressId_FK` (`AddressId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `parents`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `parents`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `parents` (
  `ParentId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  `FirstName` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `MiddleName` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `InstitutionId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  `UserId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  PRIMARY KEY (`ParentId`),
  KEY `InstitutionId_Parents_FK` (`InstitutionId`),
  KEY `UserId_Parents_FK` (`UserId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `permissions`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `permissions`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `permissions` (
  `PermissionId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  `PermissionCategory` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `PermissionName` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PermissionId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `roles`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `roles`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `roles` (
  `RoleId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  `RoleType` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `InstitutionId` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RoleId`),
  KEY `InstitutionId_Roles_FK` (`InstitutionId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `roles_permissions`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `roles_permissions`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `roles_permissions` (
  `RoleId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  `PermissionId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  `InstitutionId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  KEY `RoleId_Roles_Permissions_FK` (`RoleId`),
  KEY `PermissionId_Roles_Permissions_FK` (`PermissionId`),
  KEY `InstitutionId_Roles_Permissions_FK` (`InstitutionId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `routes`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `routes`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `routes` (
  `RouteId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  `RouteName` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `Mon` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Tue` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Wed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Thu` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Fri` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Sat` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Sun` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `StartDate` date NOT NULL,
  `EndDate` date NOT NULL,
  `StartTime` time NOT NULL,
  `EndTime` time NOT NULL,
  `CurrentNumberOfBookings` int NOT NULL,
  `InstitutionId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  PRIMARY KEY (`RouteId`),
  KEY `InstitutionId_Routes_FK` (`InstitutionId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `routes_stops`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `routes_stops`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `routes_stops` (
  `RouteId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  `StopId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  `Time` time NOT NULL,
  `InstitutionId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  KEY `RouteId_RoutesStops_FK` (`RouteId`),
  KEY `StopId_RoutesStops_FK` (`StopId`),
  KEY `InstitutionId_RoutesStops_FK` (`InstitutionId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `staff`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `staff`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `staff` (
  `StaffId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  `InstitutionId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  `FirstName` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `MiddleName` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `UserId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  KEY `UserId_FK` (`UserId`),
  KEY `InstitutionId_Staff_FK` (`InstitutionId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `stops`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `stops`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stops` (
  `StopId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  `StopName` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `Longitude` decimal(9,6) NOT NULL,
  `Latitude` decimal(9,6) NOT NULL,
  `AddressId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  `InstitutionId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  PRIMARY KEY (`StopId`),
  KEY `AddressId_Stops_FK` (`AddressId`),
  KEY `InstitutionId_Stops_FK` (`InstitutionId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `students`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `students`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `students` (
  `StudentId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  `FirstName` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `MiddleName` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `DateOfBirth` date NOT NULL,
  `InstitutionId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  PRIMARY KEY (`StudentId`),
  KEY `InstitutionId_Student_FK` (`InstitutionId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `students_parents`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `students_parents`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `students_parents` (
  `StudentId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  `ParentId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  `InstitutionId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  KEY `StudentId_StudentParent_FK` (`StudentId`),
  KEY `ParentId_StudentParent_FK` (`ParentId`),
  KEY `InstitutionId_StudentParent_FK` (`InstitutionId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `UserId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  `Email` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Password` char(60) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `InstitutionId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  `RoleId` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid())),
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserId`),
  KEY `InstitutionId_FK` (`InstitutionId`),
  KEY `RoleId_Users_FK` (`RoleId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `bookings`
--
ALTER TABLE `bookings`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `InstitutionId_Bookings_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`InstitutionId`) REFERENCES `institutions` (`InstitutionId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `RouteId_Bookings_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`RouteId`) REFERENCES `routes_stops` (`RouteId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `StopId_Bookings_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`StopId`) REFERENCES `routes_stops` (`StopId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `StudentId_Bookings_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`StudentId`) REFERENCES `students` (`StudentId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `UserId_Bookings_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `users` (`UserId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `buses`
--
ALTER TABLE `buses`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `InstitutionId_Buses_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`InstitutionId`) REFERENCES `institutions` (`InstitutionId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `buses_routes`
--
ALTER TABLE `buses_routes`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `BusId_BusesRoutes_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`BusId`) REFERENCES `buses` (`BusId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `InstitutionId_BusesRoutes_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`InstitutionId`) REFERENCES `institutions` (`InstitutionId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `RouteId_BusesRoutes_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`RouteId`) REFERENCES `routes` (`RouteId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `drivers`
--
ALTER TABLE `drivers`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `BusId_Drivers_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`BusId`) REFERENCES `buses` (`BusId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `InstitutionId_Drivers_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`InstitutionId`) REFERENCES `institutions` (`InstitutionId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `UserId_Drivers_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `users` (`UserId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `institutions`
--
ALTER TABLE `institutions`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `AddressId_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`AddressId`) REFERENCES `addresses` (`AddressId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `parents`
--
ALTER TABLE `parents`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `InstitutionId_Parents_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`InstitutionId`) REFERENCES `institutions` (`InstitutionId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `UserId_Parents_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `users` (`UserId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `roles`
--
ALTER TABLE `roles`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `InstitutionId_Roles_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`InstitutionId`) REFERENCES `institutions` (`InstitutionId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `roles_permissions`
--
ALTER TABLE `roles_permissions`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `InstitutionId_Roles_Permissions_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`InstitutionId`) REFERENCES `institutions` (`InstitutionId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `PermissionId_Roles_Permissions_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`PermissionId`) REFERENCES `permissions` (`PermissionId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `RoleId_Roles_Permissions_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`RoleId`) REFERENCES `roles` (`RoleId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `routes`
--
ALTER TABLE `routes`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `InstitutionId_Routes_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`InstitutionId`) REFERENCES `institutions` (`InstitutionId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `routes_stops`
--
ALTER TABLE `routes_stops`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `InstitutionId_RoutesStops_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`InstitutionId`) REFERENCES `institutions` (`InstitutionId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `RouteId_RoutesStops_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`RouteId`) REFERENCES `routes` (`RouteId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `StopId_RoutesStops_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`StopId`) REFERENCES `stops` (`StopId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `staff`
--
ALTER TABLE `staff`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `InstitutionId_Staff_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`InstitutionId`) REFERENCES `institutions` (`InstitutionId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `UserId_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `users` (`UserId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `stops`
--
ALTER TABLE `stops`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `AddressId_Stops_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`AddressId`) REFERENCES `addresses` (`AddressId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `InstitutionId_Stops_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`InstitutionId`) REFERENCES `institutions` (`InstitutionId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `students`
--
ALTER TABLE `students`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `InstitutionId_Student_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`InstitutionId`) REFERENCES `institutions` (`InstitutionId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `students_parents`
--
ALTER TABLE `students_parents`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `InstitutionId_StudentParent_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`InstitutionId`) REFERENCES `institutions` (`InstitutionId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `ParentId_StudentParent_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`ParentId`) REFERENCES `parents` (`ParentId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `StudentId_StudentParent_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`StudentId`) REFERENCES `students` (`StudentId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `InstitutionId_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`InstitutionId`) REFERENCES `institutions` (`InstitutionId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `RoleId_Users_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`RoleId`) REFERENCES `roles` (`RoleId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: When you mentioned C# and tagged the question as `sql-server` I assumed you were using Microsoft SQL Server, but by your code it looks like you're using MySQL for the database system. Please update your question tags with the specific database system and version, as those are generally required (and you can remove the `sql-server` tag if your question isn't about Microsoft SQL Server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quickly scanned your SQL file that generates your schema. I think you're off to a good start, a lot of it makes sense. These are the things that stood out to me that you might want to think about a little more (or some may make sense as is, based on your domain knowledge):

1. Storing the `BusId` column in `drivers` table limits you to only being able to define one driver per bus at a given time. I would expect this to be more `route` or `booking` dependent, as theoretically buses can be used by different drivers across different routes over different days. Or what happens if the normal `driver` for a given `bus` is out sick?...then a different `driver` could even take over. Another table of `bus_drivers` with a many-to-many relationship might be helpful here.
2. I don't think you have a need to store the `InstitutionId` on a lot of tables, as it appears to be redundant since you're able to access it referentially. For example, the `parents` table is referenced by `students_parents` which also references `students`. The `InstitutionId` already exists in `students` and therefore is redundant in the `parents` table and `students_parents` table.
3. The `routes` table has the *Monday through Friday* columns (e.g. `Mon`, `Tue`, etc). I assume this is a way to denote which `routes` operate on which days. This is ok, but might be better and give you more flexibility if you stored this information in a `schedules` table instead, that is perhaps driven by actual dates. Since again you can run into multiple situations like a `route` that is normally scheduled for Mondays but this coming Monday is a holiday so it actually isn't active that day this one time.

Outside of the above suggestions, to directly answer your questions on **primary keys**, yes you should always try to create a **primary key** on every table (except rare cases with staging tables, but that's not relevant to your schema here). Should they be the `UUID` data type is up to you. Though generally that's only important in cases where your database system runs distributed across multiple consumers who will be generating data simultaneously in parallel **outside of your centralized database** and you need a way to eventually consolidate that data into one centralized database, as a way to ensure global uniqueness. For example, in the context of a mobile application that allows users to create data while their device is offline and stores it in a local database on the device until they're back online and then synchronizes it to the main centralized database. Even in that scenario there are ways to use a different data type like an integer identity column as your **primary key** on the centralized database.

If your scenario doesn't involve the above use case, then I'd strongly recommend using an [integer based auto_increment identity column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) as your **primary key** in each table. It'll require less data storage, guarantee uniqueness (since only one database is at play), auto generate itself, and more importantly be more efficient to index and `JOIN` on between your tables.

Comment: Thanks J.D for the thorough answer - this definitely helps and I’m glad I wasn’t too far off! There is a possibility that if the internet is down, I’d like users to still be able to store their information for later uploading (from a csv or json perhaps). Is there a huge performance difference with using UUID versus an int that’s auto incremented? Also, for organisation IDs... or company IDs... do people tend to use UUIDs? Or do they use something as simple as int autoincrement? Thanks for the advice on the tables, I’ll also look into that :)

Comment: @SuzanAydın Absolutely, no problem! It depends on your definition of *huge* and what's *acceptable* in your system, and it really depends on the exact queries you're running, e.g. if typically your queries only get a few number of rows that result in **index seeks** vs **index scans** on the `UUID` **keys**. I've definitely seen cases where `UUID` is up to four times as slow as an `INT` but I wouldn't expect them to be 100x slower. Though another factor in performance of `UUID` fields is their randomness in values tends to result in index fragmentation much more easily than on an `INT` field.

Comment: The thing a lot of developers forget, even in the case of distributed parallel data generation that later needs to be consolidated, is that `UUID` isn't guaranteed to be globally unique 100% of the time, even though it usually is unique. But to be a good developer, one should still implement collision handling during the data consolidation process. My opinion is if we're already going to the extent of implementing collision handling logic, then it's not much different to implement such logic when the colliding data type is an `INT` or any data type for that matter. So I personally see no...

Comment: ...benefit in the `UUID` data type in most cases, even with distributed parallel data generation that needs to be consolidated. The one case where I do find it has a use, is it obfuscates the order in which that record was generated, which is useful in certain use cases / contexts where security is a factor, to prevent someone from guessing the `ID` of another record. But I digress since this is a little outside the scope of your question. :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation J.D :). I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to DBs... i'm a developer by heart where I've only touched on SQL here and there. I can design a DB to the best of my ability with relational knowledge but when you mentioned collision handling you lost me a bit... Do you have a good example of collision handling? I'm happy to modify it all to be an int as the ID if necessary, but I'm not too sure how to handle collisions (i'm assuming this is when one client on another machine tries to modify a row and someone else on another machine tries to do the same)..

Comment: @SuzanAydın No worries, **collision handling** in this context means **key collisions**, e.g. if in offline mode two `UUIDs` are generated with the same values in two different offline systems (by two different users). When those same values for the **primary key** are inserted into the consolidated database (once back online), an error will be thrown since the **primary key** of a table needs to be unique. `UUID`s don't normally collide, but it does definitely happen, I've experienced it plenty. Unfortunately a quick Googly hasn't turned up any literature I think would be sufficient, but...

Comment: ...usually the solution to collision handling is to detect and catch collision errors during data consolidation and just re-generate a new key. The odds of a second collision happening with `UUID` is very unlikely, and becomes less likely on each subsequent collision, should one occur. In the case of an **auto_increment** `INT` identity column, you're instead letting the centralized database generate the **primary key** values for you on `INSERT`, so you'd have to get the newly generated `ID` after `INSERT` and update the local database entity's **keys** accordingly, a bi-directional fix.

Comment: Thanks J.D. I've seen retrieving the newly inserted ID and I have seen issues with this, basically with what you're talking about, where one online system can insert into the same table as another online system is inserting, and the first system tries to retrieve the newly inserted ID but retrieves the one created by the second system, if that makes sense. I don't know if i've found a solution to that. I suppose in the code (in my case, the C# code triggering an insert), if the insert fails with "UUID already present" or some such, I can just try to do the insert again until it succeeds?

Comment: @SuzanAydin Typically database systems have built in mechanisms to track the `INSERT` to the scope of the connection or call that created the `INSERT` to prevent concurrency issues. For example in Microsoft SQL Server they have a function called [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for this very case to ensure you only get the most recent identity value your `INSERT` created. Unfortunately I'm not as familiar with MySQL and wouldn't know what the mechanism is called there.

Comment: If you do stick with a `UUID` though, then yes for collision issues you basically just need to ensure you catch the exception that's thrown for a duplicate key trying to be inserted, and then re-generate a new `UUID` and retry, rinse and repeat on any subsequent collisions.

Comment: Thanks JD you've been super helpful :)

Comment: @SuzanAydın No problem! Glad to be of help! 

Comment: I was thinking J.D, how would you integrate a schedules table? I'm thinking since it's for a school, it'll need to have the potential to take into account holiday periods and exclude them for certain routes. Do you have an idea? Trying to formulate it in a table

Comment: @SuzanAydin I'd have to think about it a little bit, but one way to do it, speaking at a high level, is it would have the fields `ScheduleId, RouteId, ScheduleDateTime` (possibly the `InstitutionId` too if the same `Route` can be used by multiple `Institutions` but need different `Schedules`). Every row in the table would be a single date & time of that particular `Route's` `Schedule`. For example, if Route123 had a schedule for only Mondays at 3PM, there'd be a row in there for every valid Monday that `Route` needs scheduled. E.g. if the school year is only 40 weeks long, then you'd have...

Comment: ...40 rows of dates (for Mondays) at 3 PM in the `ScheduleDateTime` column. Doing it this was may result in a larger table by number of rows, and forces the work of generating the schedules / determining which dates to skip every year (or however often you can foreseeably determine) downstream in your application code. So this kind of implementation may or may not be good. Alternatively you can have a separate `DatesDimension` table which stores the calendar years for the next X number of years (I usually generate 100 years) and has all the holidays etc built into it. There's SQL scripts...

Comment: ...out there that'll generate the `DatesDimension` table for you. (Unfortunately I'm only familiar with Microsoft SQL Server so [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) is what I'd use but you'd need a MySQL equivalent.) They're pretty cool though, they have all the dates, fields to specify different holidays, weekends, and different formats of the dates such as which week of the year a particular date is in, or the numerical representation of a given date etc. So if you generated one of these tables you could then have a...

Comment: ...more generic `Schedules` table that specified which day of the week a particular `Route's` `Schedule` is for (e.g. Monday, Wednesday, Friday) and you'd only have to join it to your `DatesDimension` table whenever you wanted to get all the Mondays for a given year, for example. Then you can see which Mondays are holidays and filter them out, etc. Even in the generic `Schedule` table above, I'd still store a separate row per day, so in my same example you'd have 3 rows total for Monday, Wednesday, Friday for a particular `Route` (but that's still better than my previous suggestion) and you...

Comment: ...wouldn't have to worry about maintaining the schedules every year (or at least not as frequently) in your application because it would be based off your `DatesDimension` table that you'd only have to generate once and can be generated for any number of years needed

Comment: Thanks for this J.D! Curious though, different schools have different "holidays" (excluding public holidays) i.e. they might have holiday club between 25th March to 13th April (buses may not operate between this time). These are obviously not public holidays, and this will differ between schools. Should I create a dates dimension table and a separate holiday table with institution ID as a foreign key? Sorry for all the qs!

Comment: Maybe a holidays table with columns HolidayId, DayId (from DatesDimension) and InstitutionId

Comment: @SuzanAydin Yea I think that sounds reasonable. A dates dimension table is good for global generic stuff around dates (and should be part a more generic shared schema if you plan to have other applications, because it could be useful for those applications as well), but for the individual *custom holidays* for the schools, a separate table might be good idea that stores the dates with the `InstitutionId`, and can always be re-joined to your dates dimension table for additional information about those days as needed (like what day of the week it is, etc).

Comment: Thanks again J.D xD